# Are questions of the form "Is this correct?" acceptable here?

Tags: discussion

I've been a member of this site for a couple weeks now, and am finding it to be an amazing source for getting input from many knowledgeable people on a topic.

I know that one of the primary goals of all the stackexchange sites is provide answers to questions that will be useful to *others* in the future.

Some of my questions about music theory fit well into this framework, such as [What two keys are associated with a fix dominant 7th chord?](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/64261/what-two-keys-are-associated-with-a-fix-dominant-7th-chord) or [9/8 hybrid vs compound time](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/64097/9-8-hybrid-vs-compound-time), for example.

But questions like [Is this cadence correctly written?](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/64354/is-this-cadence-correctly-written) include a snapshot of an exercise I have completed, and I'm looking for someone to either confirm it is correct, or tell me it is wrong.

Is this an acceptable use of this site?  I don't want to be seen as abusing the site.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That cadence question actually does work because you have written it well. On its own, it could be argued that any number of answers could be possible depending on opinions, but you have framed it well, and as you can see from the answers they have understood what you are asking.

In terms of value to future visitors, again yes - I think this provides a learning point applicable across composition, not just to that one specific query you had.

In summary -looks good. Keep it up :-)